# How to send an integer value in POST request params using UnityWebRequest?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add a Multipart form data section to UnityWebRequest that contains a key whose value is an integer. Below is my code for the same:

```
List<IMultipartFormSection> formData = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("uploadType", 5));
```

But this is throwing an error saying cannot convert from int to byte[]. I checked the API spec for MultipartFormDataSection and it accepts (string, byte[]) only.

Is there a way I can attach an int value instead of a byte array in the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument for `MultipartFormDataSection` takes string or byte array. Just convert the `int` you want to send to `string` then pass it to `MultipartFormDataSection` data argument.

```
formData.Add(new MultipartFormDataSection("uploadType", Convert.ToString(5)));
```